# Another way to clone a picture & image in a larger view

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner developer and I work with Reactjs.

I'm doing a project where there will be a gallery of photos that I brought 
from a flickr api service.

Each image will have two buttons:

1.Clone: clicking the clone button should duplicate the image.

2.Expand: clicking an image should display this image in a larger view

How do I clone the image in a different way than I did? (more effective)

How do I large the image without using the 'react-modal'?

I have two components- One of the gallery and the other of the pictures.

my Gallery.js:

```
handleClone = image => {
this.state.images.push(image);
this.setState({ images: this.state.images });
 };

render() {
 return (
  <div className="gallery-root">
    {this.state.images.map((dto, index) => {
      return <Image key={'image-' + index} dto={dto} galleryWidth= 
        {this.state.galleryWidth}
      handleClone={image => this.handleClone(image)}
      />;
    })}
   </div>
  );
 }
```

my Image.js:

```
handleClone() {
this.props.handleClone(this.props.dto); // send to the Gallery component 
 the image to clone.
}

render() {
return (

    <div>
      <FontAwesome className="image-icon" name="clone" title="clone" 
       onClick={()=> this.handleClone()}/>
      <FontAwesome className="image-icon" name="filter" title="filter" 
       onClick={()=> this.filterChange()}/>
      <FontAwesome className="image-icon" name="expand" title="expand" />
    </div>
  </div>
 );
 }
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the clone purposes.

```
handleClone = image => {
  const imagesCopy = [...this.state.images]; //creates a copy of the images array which is stored in your component.
  imagesCopy.push(image);
  //this.state.images.push(image); this way will mutate the state directly which is a mistake.
  this.setState({ images: imagesCopy });
};
```

About the `react-modal` thing, I don't see anything related to that in the question post, can you please share out the related code?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer solved my problem!

Comment: I am really glad!